# Regex matching terminating quote only if quote at the beginning

Tags: regex

I want to match the following element with regex

```
target="#MOBILE"
```

and all valid variants.

I've written the regex

```
target[\s\S]*#MOBILE[^>^\s]*
```

which matches the following

```
target="#MOBILE"
target = "#MOBILE"
target=#MOBILE
target="#MOBILE" (followed directly by >)
```

but it doesn't match

```
target=" #MOBILE "
```

properly (note the extra space). It only matches

```
target=" #MOBILE
```

missing out the final quote

What I need is the terminating expression `[^>^\s]*` to match a quote only if it matches a quote at the beginning. It also needs to work with single quotes. The terminating expression also needs to end with a whitespace or `>` char as it does currently.

I'm sure there is a way to do this - but I'm not sure how. It's probably standard stuff - I just don't know it

Incidently I'm not sure that `[^>^\s]*` is the best way to terminate if the regex hits a `space` or `>` char but it's the only way that I can get it to work.

Comment: I think there may be an error in your post.  The regex says nothing about quotation marks and `target=" #MOBILE "` does match for me.

Comment: Which language? Does it support [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)? In that case try: `target\s*=\s*("?)#MOBILE(\1|\s|>)`

Comment: The regex doesn't terminate with quotes i.e. [^>^\s]* but it needs to only if there is a quote at the question. There is an error of sorts in the regex - i guess that's the question

Comment: It's targeting asp.net and c#. Should have put that - apologies

Comment: @Malvolio The regex allows quotes before #MOBILE. `[\s\S]*MOBILE` means that before the word MOBILE, there can be any amount of characters which are whitespace or are not whitespace. That is, basically any character at all. So it could be `=2dva2"#MOBILE`. Basically `[\s\S]*MOBILE` is the same as `.*MOBILE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), similar to jensgram's suggestion:

```
target\s*=\s*(?:(")\s*)?#Mobile\s*\1
```

`(?:(")\s*)?` - Optional non-capturing group that contains a quote (which is captured), and additional optional spaces. If it matched, `\1` will contain a quote.

Working example: http://regexr.com?2vkkq

A better alternative for .Net (mainly because you want single quotes, and `\1` behaves differently for uncaptured groups):

```
target\s*=\s*(["']?)\s*?#Mobile\s*\1
```

Working example: [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=target%5cs%2a%3d%5cs%2a%28%5b%22%27%5d%3f%29%5cs%2a%3f%23Mobile%5cs%2a%5c1&i=target%3d%22%23MOBILE%22+target+%3d+%22%23MOBILE%22+target%3d%23MOBILE+target%3d%22%23MOBILE%22%3e+target%3d%22+%23MOBILE+%22+target+%3d+%22+%23mobile+&o=i)

Comment: brilliant - works. Thaks for your help. Just what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try the following if you need to check that your quotes are in pairs:

```
target\s*=\s*(['"])(?=\1)\s*#MOBILE\s*(?<=\1)\1
```

But it really depends if your regex engine supports positive `look-(ahead|behind)` syntax. And if it supports back-referencing.

Comment: That's great. Thanks (other poster just got there before you - sorry)

Comment: As a note - it doesn't work with ASP.Net engine. I'm sure it's because of the caveats you outlined

Answer (score 0):

Without quotes `target\s*=\s*#MOBILE`

With double quotes `target\s*=\s*"\s*#MOBILE\s*"`

With single quotes `target\s*=\s*'\s*#MOBILE\s*'`

All together

`(target\s*=\s*#MOBILE)|(target\s*=\s*"\s*#MOBILE\s*")|(target\s*=\s*'\s*#MOBILE\s*')`

Or someone can make it neater.

Comment: thanks - doesn't match target='#MOBILE' for some reason. Looks like it should

Comment: @TimBrown Are you sure that's not because you're using different characters? Remember that there is a difference between ` and ´ and '